# Sharing image via my app in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I want to share an image. Sharing options should contain my app xyz. For example if I open an image and want to share it on instagram sharing options contains instagram,facebook,twitter,email etc. Like that my app should be in sharing options. How can I do that in xamarin.forms(both ios and android).

Answer (score 1):

I think the app icon is created in a directory that is private to your app, so other apps wont be able to get at it.

You will need to save it out somewhere where the other apps can access it then share it from that location some thing like this:

```
public void Share (string title, string content)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty (title) || string.IsNullOrEmpty (content))
                return;

    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources,Resource.Drawable.icon_120);

    var tempFilename = "test.png";
    var sdCardPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
    var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(sdCardPath, tempFilename);
    using (var os = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        b.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, os);
    }
    b.Dispose ();

    var imageUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse ($"file://{sdCardPath}/{tempFilename}");
    var sharingIntent = new Intent ();
    sharingIntent.SetAction (Intent.ActionSend);
    sharingIntent.SetType ("image/*");
    sharingIntent.PutExtra (Intent.ExtraText, content);
    sharingIntent.PutExtra (Intent.ExtraStream, imageUri);
    sharingIntent.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
    StartActivity (Intent.CreateChooser (sharingIntent, title));
}
```

Also add ReadExternalStorage and WriteExternalStorage permissions to your app.

Let me know if that works.

Comment: I want to do exactly opposite to it. @sumeet

Comment: I want my app in sharing options.